# `ImportError: No module named pyautocad` whenever I try to create an exe with py2exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

Not sure whats happening and why py2exe is unable to find the module. My `setup.py` file is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import shutil

setup(windows=["RotoWorks.py"], options={'py2exe': {'includes': ['pyautocad']}})
```

I'm not sure where to start or how to reason why py2exe is unable to import `pyautocad`. If I open up IDLE or just the python shell and type `import pyautocad`, it imports fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your pyautocad.pyd.
Py2exe is structured otherwise than python interpreter, which looks into site-packages for modules...

you could do it with like (**no exact code, just structural proposal..!**):

```
import glob, shutil, py2exe

correct_Pyd_file = 'none'
for file in glob.glob('*.pyd'):
   if file.startswith("pyautocad"):
      correct_Pyd_file = file

correct_Pyd_file.strip('.pyd') #strip ending for py2exe


opts = {'py2exe': {'compressed': True, "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"], "includes" : ["sip"]}}

setup(console=[{"script" : "main.py"}], options=opts, data_files=correct_Pyd_file)
shutil.rmtree('build', ignore_errors=True)     #Remove the build folder
```